# SymPy doesn't render multi-character subscripts correctly

Tags: python, sympy

How do I create a SymPy symbol that has a multi-character string for a subscript which renders properly with pretty printing?

The following render correctly:

```
symbols('tau_12')
symbols('tau_x')
```

but I cannot get the following to render the subscript correctly:

```
symbols('tau_xy')
```

How do I get a multi-character subscript?

Comment: I get the correct output using https://www.wakari.io/wakari Ipython notebook.  Have you done `init_printing()` ?  What platform / version are you working with?

Comment: https://www.wakari.io/sharing/bundle/galtay/multisubscript

Comment: It works in IPython notebook but not the IPython console.

Comment: well, basically you put them the multi-character subscript/superscript in curly brackets. for example `a_{12}` and `a_{xy}`. This only works for non-Greek letters though.

Comment: I think you can find the solution [here in galgebra library](https://github.com/brombo/galgebra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Unicode only has a limited set of characters as subscripts (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Other_superscript_and_subscript_characters). In particular, there is no Unicode character for subscript `y`.  Your best bet if you want prettier printing is to use the IPython notebook or qtconsole, where you can get rendered math using MathJax or LaTeX.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you want?

```
xi1 = Symbol('x_i^{(1)}')
xi1
```

[image]